# ClickOnce exe files needs unblock to work

Tags: .net, exe, block, clickonce, sign

I have a problem after deploying ClickOnce applications to client hosts. After the deployment successfully completes and a shortcut is added to the desktop, running the application will cause ClickOnce to check for new version of the application but nothing else to happen afterwards.

I have found a workaround to the problem which includes finding the .exe file of the app in the `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\<path_to_app>\<app_name>.exe` and then opening the properties of the file and choosing "Unblock" which - up to my knowledge - is set by Windows SmartScreen.

I want a better solution to this, which enables ClickOnce to install the app without getting it blocked in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, that is certainly not normal.  Consider that this might have happened *before* you published the ClickOnce app.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it happened before since the app works normally on my production host (SmartScreen doesn't filter exe produced in the same device).

Comment: I did a little research and seems like I can get an EV Code Signing Certificate and use it to sign my app, which will enable the Windows of the client host to accept my .exe files without blocking them. I am not sure it will work though. Seems like I am going to end up making a script for unblocking files to run it on client hosts.

Comment: It is not SmartScreen that does this, spend your money on something better.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem. I also want to get this fixed.
After some research, I found some information. In latest windows 10 update in April/May, Microsoft have increased the security level of Windows Defender. Whenever we install newer version of clickonce application, it treats the application downloaded from unknown source. So, it blocks the application. We have to go to the appdata folder & unblock the exe or run the exe in admin mode using the Run As Administrator mode.